# kotlinx-serialization - Why default value inherited from base class is always encoded?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

```
@Serializable
open class A {
    val default: String = "hello"
}

@Serializable
open class B(val value: String): A()

fun main(){
    val obj = B("foo")
    val str = Json.encodeToString(obj)
    println(str)
}
```

encoding result:

> {"default":"hello","value":"foo"}

Why the default value is encoded while the encodeDefaults config is false?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to update the `kotlinx-serialization` library.

This is the code:

```
@Serializable
open class A {
    val default: String = "hello"
}

@Serializable
open class B(val value: String) : A()

private val json = Json { encodeDefaults = false }

fun main() {
    println(json.encodeToString(B("foo")))
}
```

This is the output:

```
{"value":"foo"}
```

Comment: Actually, I have tried to update the  kotlinx-serialization library to the newest version, but it didn't work . I have already reported an issue to the koltinx.serialization team, and they recommended me to update kotlin version from 1.5.10 to 1.5.20 or higher(, and kotlin-serialization gradle plugin version as well, I think). Then everything works fine. I think the kotlin-serialization gradle plugin should be to blame. The serializer class generated by compiler plugin has changed after updating. Thank you anyway.